# Query causes commit when using association table

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

Could anyone help me understand the following behaviour?  I have a simple schema where a Project has many Assets and Elements.  The Assets and Elements have a Many to Many relationship within the scope of the Project.

I need to make sure that an Element has a code that is unique within the scope of a Project, so before I add a new Element to the SQLAlchemy session I'd like to check whether an Element with the same code already exists in the Project.  What I'm finding is that, when I use an association table to map the Many to Many relationship between Elements and Assets, I can't query the database without the query action actually committing the new Element to the DB.

To be clear, I haven't **add** 'ed or **commit** 'ed this new Element to the SQLAlchemy session at this point.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, and_
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relation, backref
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

### your credentials here ###
# _MYSQL_DB = 
# _MYSQL_USER = 
# _MYSQL_PWORD = 
# _MYSQL_SCHEMATA = 
# _MYSQL_TEST_SCHEMATA = 

testEngine = create_engine("mysql://%s:%s@%s/%s"%(  _MYSQL_USER,
                                                    _MYSQL_PWORD,
                                                    _MYSQL_DB,
                                                    _MYSQL_TEST_SCHEMATA),
                                                    pool_recycle=3600,
                                                    echo=True)

Base = declarative_base()
SQLAlchemySession = sessionmaker(autoflush=True, autocommit=False)

class Project(Base):
    __tablename__ = "SA_project_t"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    code = Column(String(24), nullable=False, unique=True)

class Asset(Base):
    __tablename__ = "SA_asset_t"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    projectId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("SA_project_t.id"))
    project = relation("Project")
    code = Column(String(128))

element_to_asset_assoc = Table( "SA_elementToAssetAssoc_t",
                                Base.metadata,
                                Column("elementId", Integer, ForeignKey("SA_element_t.id")),
                                Column("assetId", Integer, ForeignKey("SA_asset_t.id")))

class Element(Base):
    __tablename__ = "SA_element_t"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    projectId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("SA_project_t.id"))
    project = relation("Project")
    code = Column(String(256))
    assets = relation("Asset", secondary=element_to_asset_assoc, backref="elements")


Base.metadata.bind=testEngine
session = SQLAlchemySession(bind=testEngine)

Base.metadata.drop_all(checkfirst=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(testEngine, checkfirst=True)

# Create a Project, Asset and Element

project = Project()
project.code = "MyProject"
session.add(project)

asset = Asset()
asset.project = project
asset.code = "MyAsset"
session.add(asset)

element = Element()
element.project = project
element.code = "MyElement"
element.assets = [asset]
session.add(element)

session.commit()

# Now I'd like to add a new element, but first check that the 
# element's code is unique within the scope of the Project

newElement = Element()
newElement.project = project
newElement.code = "MyElement"
newElement.assets = [asset]

results = session.query(Element).filter(and_( Element.project==newElement.project,
                                            Element.code==newElement.code))

# Up until this point, newElement hasn't been inserted into the 
# database, but once I query "results.count()" I find that an INSERT
# has been perfomed.  

print results.count()

# p.s. I realize that results will contain both the original and 
# new element, but I don't expect the new element to have been
# inserted into the database at this point.
```

The action of calling **count()** on the **results** variable is commiting **newElement** to the MySQL database, which is not my intention.  If I remove the association table then I get the behaviour that I expect - **newElement** is not added to the DB.

From what I can see from the log, the session sees the associated Asset as dirty at the start of the query, and flushing this triggers a commit of the **newElement**.  Is this expected behaviour?  If so, is there a way to keep the Many to Many relationship while still querying the database under these circumstances and *not* triggering a commit.

Using SQLAlchemy 0.7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to `add()` the `newElement` object, since it is automatically added to the session when you assign bound object to one of its relations. It is flushed to database when `newElement.project` property is accessed (you can use `autoflush=False` to disable this behavior).  MySQL uses MyISAM engine by default, which ignores transaction statements. Thus all flushed changes persist. To enable transaction support add `__table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB'}` to your mapped classes.

Comment: Many thanks Denis.  That's pointed me back on course.  It strikes me that my other option in this situation would be to do the query through a new SQLAlchemy session.